# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am having trouble using custom hooks inside the `useEffect` function. I have googled for hours and was unable to find a fix for this issue. Here is the chunk of code I am having an issue with:

```
  const [ stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey ] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser())

    async function getStripeApiKey() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/stripeapi');
      setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey)
    }

    getStripeApiKey();
  }, [])
```

I am trying to use the custom hook to set **Stripe API key** which I want to use later in the return function. But I am getting the following error:
[Invalid Hook Call Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiyxA.png)

Comment: how are you defining your component - is it a class component or functional component? https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: @alex I defined the component as a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a read to react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html which states **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**

Comment: thanks for your explanation but I can't find where he uses hooks inside loops or conditions. it's used straightforward in the component body as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did look it up earlier but I failed to find any fix (or workaround) for this issue. Can you please show me how to resolve this? I am new and feeling lost at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix this by using `useDispatch` hooks:

First, import it:

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
```

Second, inside of your component:

```
// rest of codes
const [ stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey ] = useState('');

const dispatch = useDispatch()
// rest of codes
```

Now, use your `dispatch` method in `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser()) // -----> replaced 

    async function getStripeApiKey() {
       try{
          const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/stripeapi');
          setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey)
       } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
          // you can do anything here
       }
    }

    getStripeApiKey();
  }, [])
```

**Note:** always use `try/catch` block with your `async/await` implementation especially when working with API calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this but still receiving the same error at the same spot (Provided in the attached image).

Comment: I updated my answer via wrap the API call function with try/catch block. please try it again and tell me about the feedback. thanks @TomalSheikh

Comment: @novomino, still did not work. Someone else might benefit from this solution though. You are an experienced developer, I believe. Do you think this issue is generated from any other chunk of code in my application? If I remove this, the app works fine. Also is there any chance that this issue is due to backend? In both cases, I have my doubts but still, I am just a beginner. And I appreciate your effort.

Comment: oh sir, thanks. I guess the problem is not related to the other parts of your application since the error message tells that. but we can debug your code together to solve the problem. for the first step, please make sure the other parts of your application are a comment, you can simplify your project and comment on other "pages/views". then focus on the "page" that produces the error. so comment on the other parts and just test your useEffect hooks. @TomalSheikh

Comment: now comment the dispatch action statement and test the getStripApiKey only. now reverse it and comment your function and allow to dispatch loadUser action.

Comment: you can test your application in this way to find out the problem. so try to comment and test every regular part of the component. please feedback me about the result @TomalSheikh